# Unable to pack images of resolution 800x800 using libGDX texture packer with stripwhitespace option?

Tags: android, libgdx, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I have 3-4 images of size 800x800 pixels . When I trying to create .pack file using gdx-texturepacker.jar, if I turn on strip whitespace X and Y option it is unable to pack and throws an error [error] Exception occured: Error packing files. but If i remove the option
strip whitespace (which i really need), it creates the pack but without serving the purpose of sprite-sheet.

For small resolution image everything is working. Is there any size limitaion for using stripwhitespace option??

Any help s appreciated and any suggestion for other free texture packing tool good for libgdx assets.

Comment: Logged in to upvote this question!  too bad no answer is found yet : (

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and fixed it by editing the `Max page width` and `Max page height` options to fit my image's needs. Ex:

[image]

I know this is 10 months old but hopefully this will help someone out in the future with a similar problem!

Comment: Thanks mate, One  more useful command I found was: `$ java -Xmx2000m -jar texturepacker-gui.jar`